# How to create Header, Body, Footer inside Column?

Tags: flutter

I need to create something like this (I am talking about right side from palceholder):

[image]

I wrote next code:

```
Card(
      child: Container(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Placeholder(
          fallbackHeight: 100,
          fallbackWidth: 100,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             SizedBox(
               child: Text("Header"),
             ),
             Flexible(child: Text("Body"), flex: 2),
             Text("Footer"),
            ]

          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
  );
```

But result is:
[image]

Comment: Simply remove the `SizedBox` and replace `Flexible` with `Expanded`. You can also remove `flex` as it defaults to 1 which still takes all available space as it's the only widget within the `Column` with a `flex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**// Updated**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double _deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: filmListList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: _deviceHeight,
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: I am getting error in first variant https://images.guru/i/1bJXg

Comment: I see. You have a list of cards. You use them in a list view? Horizontally or Vertically?

Comment: I need them vertically. Like stack.

Comment: Should one card take full screen and then scroll vertically to view next?

Comment: why I could place Container inside Flexible? I tried to place Text inside Flexible and got failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200901/discussion-between-praneeth-dhanushka-fernando-and-dmitry-bubnenkov).